# queryPurchasesAsync return empty when subscriptions expired

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

I test to buy subscription in sandbox ,but the subscription canceled and expired when the auto-renew reach 6 times.
Then nothing was returned with calling `queryPurchasesAsync`.
I think it would always return the subscription information which had bought ,no matter
it was canceled or expired.
Does it happen only in sandbox or product environment ?
What is the reliable way to get subscription history ?